# pytelegrambotapi | отправка изображений от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

я хочу сделать простого эхо-бота, мне надо, что бы бот отправлял изображения, которые отправили боту.
Вот что я пробовал:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(' :) ')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.photo)
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Но в ответ я получаю не изображение, а информацию о нём.

```
{'file_size': 4501, 'file_unique_id': 'AQADGziGoi4AA4XVAAI', 'height': 150, 'width': 320, 'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAMMYG25zZrjBpZCSa1KFPn9AztxveIAApqyMRslJmlL5CnNbrxFOx0bOIaiLgADAQADAgADbQADhdUAAh4E'}
```

Как используя message.photo отправить **изображение**?

Comment: `bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, message.photo)`?

Comment: ```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
``` Я так пологаю ошибка в ```def get_text_messages(message):```, но что писать вместо ```text```?

Comment: `bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, message.photo[0].file_id)`? Судя по этому коду можно `file_id` передавать: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/888c7a6b0d97c376947ee7b525d4b70583acc3fc/tests/test_telebot.py#L185

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `send_photo` и достаточно в параметре указать id файла картинки:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, message.photo[0].file_id)
```

Comment: А как сделать тоже самое, но с видео? Просто заменить ```photo``` на ```video```?

Comment: @Cergey2202, по идеи, да

Comment: Но по факту, ошибка: File "<string>", line 6, in get_text_messages TypeError: 'Video' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Cergey2202, думаю потому что можно только одно видео за раз прислать, в отличии от фоток, поэтому там не список, а сам объект, поэтому: `message.video.file_id`

Comment: ._. ```2021-04-07 18:06:32,323 (__init__.py:526 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: type of file mismatch"```

Comment: А вы какой функцией отправляли видео?

Comment: send_document()

Comment: Это же видео, значит нужно использовать `send_video`

Comment: https://youtu.be/k6T3w3-Saj4